# How to type hint an (arbitrary) collection of some data type in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

If I have a function similar to:

```py
def some_function(paths):
    for path in paths:
        other_function(path)
```

what is the correct way to type hint `paths`? The intention of the function is that each object inside `paths` is a string, but obviously `paths` could be a list, tuple, set, numpy array, pandas Series etc. so the following seems too specific:

```py
def some_function(paths: list[str]):
    for path in paths:
        other_function(path)
```

Should I be using either `Collection` or `Sequence` from the `typing` module?

Comment: [Typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) may help. There's `Sequence`, `Iterator`, and `Iterable`.

Comment: I'd probably use `Iterable`, since the only thing you seen to care about is that you can iterate through them.

Comment: I strongly suspect the correct type of the contents of the iterable might be better specified using [`os.PathLike`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike).

Comment: just to clear up: the variable name `paths` in this case is arbitrary, and isn't supposed to represent a collection of file paths. My fault for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only thing you rely on here is iterability, ask for that.

```
from typing import Iterable

def some_function(paths: Iterable[str]):
    for path in paths:
        other_function(path)
```

If these really are supposed to be file-system paths, you might tweak it to allow `str` or anything supporting the [`os.PathLike` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike):

```
import os
from typing import Iterable

def some_function(paths: Iterable[str | os.PathLike]):  # On older Python, Iterable[Union[str, os.PathLike]]
    for path in paths:
        other_function(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want paths to be just a string then,

```py
def some_function(paths: str):
```

If you want the function to accept any number of strings you can use the * operator

```py
def some_function(*paths: str):
```

Keep in mind type hinting is only a suggestion, python will not test for correct input argument type.